# How to set the buttons in a different language in IntroJs

Tags: jquery, intro.js

I use introJS. My main audience of Russia. How to set the control buttons in the language other than english?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `setOptions({nextLabel: 'Далее', prevLabel: 'Назад', doneLabel: 'Закрыть'})`